# Overlapping using fixed in CSS

Tags: html, css, fixed

I am working on my website locally so cannot display it. I have fixed (`position: fixed;`) my header which contains my logo and menu ("Header"). The reason why I have done this is because I would like the Header to remain with the user as they scroll down the site.

Throughout the CSS, I do not use `px` but rather use `100%` for the width and auto as my height. I find auto is the best solution when viewing the site on different monitor sizes and screensizes as it stretches or gets smaller.

However, since I have set the Header as fixed, the only problem I am experiencing now is that when the screen gets smaller, the Header starts to overlap with the images and text. Since the Header is sold black, the text and images start to "disappear".

After reading and testing, "fixed" in CSS is obviously causing the problem as that part remains fixed regardless of the screen size.

Can anyone assist me and recommend what is the best course of action to take so that my Header remains "fixed" so that it remains with the user and when the screensize gets smaller, it does not cause any overlapping issues?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to have a padding-top for following content. Say if your header is 100px height, the container which has content should have `padding-top:100px`. Not having this should overlap your content in bigger size as well, if it is happening only on smaller screensize there could be some other issue. Try creating a JSFiddle replicating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a javascript to listen for resize event, than if the size is changes beyond some agreeable limit, you could update the header from `fixed` to `absolute` (or whatever works), or hide it or however you would like to handle the "too small" issue.

perhaps somethings like this:

**css**

```
#my_header { position:fixed;}
```

**js**

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // check if window size is too small for fixed, if so:
    // document.getElementById("my_header").position = "absolute";
}
```

Hope that helps on the way and good luck!